# How to cycle shades of one color on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, colors

I'm stuck on a project. I need to use javaScript/jQuery to create a box that changes colors when clicked. However, the colors that it cycles through can only be shades of green spanning from black to pure green (i.e. "#000000" --> "#00ff00"). Would it then be possible, once "#00ff00" is displayed, if it further changed the tint all the way to "#ffffff" and then cycled back to "#000000"

Additionally, I would need a second string of code that does the opposite (spans from "#ffffff" to "#00ff00" to "#000000").

In an ideal world, there would also be an output log that presents each selection as it is clicked. How do I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color)+10;
  var c = div.dataset.color%256;
  div.style.background = 'rgb(0,'+c+',0)';
})
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Not sure if that's what you looking for, but here's loop black>green>white:

```js
var div = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
div.dataset.color = 0;
div.addEventListener('click',()=>{
  div.dataset.color = parseInt(div.dataset.color)+10;
  var c = Math.min(div.dataset.color%512,255);
  var c2 = Math.max((div.dataset.color%512)-255,0);
  div.style.background = 'rgb('+c2+','+c+','+c2+')';
})
```

```css
#myDiv {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Just change **var c = div.dataset.color%256;** to **var c = 255 - div.dataset.color%256;**